# c syntax in two different lines?

Tags: c, coding-style

I have this simple question about c syntax. When we write :

```
  printf("hello world
  ");
```

compiler produces an error. Why? In this other case:

```
  for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE - 1      
  && (c=getchar)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
```

everything compiles fine. What is the general rule for all this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 9):

A *string literal* (`"..."`) cannot contain a bare newline.

If you want a newline character in the string, use the `\n` escape sequence (`"hello world\n")

Comment: I know what you're saying, but the way you've said it is somewhat confusing. A string literal can obviously contain a newline ("...\n"), but it's not written or expressed as a literal newline in code. Instead, use the escape sequence '\n' to represent a newline character; the compiler will translate that to the appropriate character. (@SLaks, I know you know that -- just trying to clarify for the benefit of anyone who might need to ask in the first place.)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're breaking a string literal, which isn't allowed, in the first example. In the second, you're just wrapping the syntax over multiple lines. For example:

```
printf("hello world"
);
```

will compile.